# Python for google app engine code

Tags: python

friends, I am using python, How do i pass a html file in response.out.write...
I feel difficulty in writing "response.out.write" in every line. I just want to write a separate html file and pass that as response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2):

I'll follow up with more research for you to have a look at; the Google App Engine 'getting started' guide for Python has two consecutive pages [Using Templates](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates) and [Using Static Files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles).  These will show you how to use static HTML files alongside your app code, and if you want to, how to use the **jinja** library to dynamically generate small parts of these static files using templates.

If you haven't seen these pages before, I highly recommend reading the whole getting started guide if you feel a bit shaky on how to use the App Engine - for Python, it starts [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/introduction)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **jinja** templating library.

```
# Load Jinja
jinja = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader("Page directory here"))
# Get your template
template = jinja.get_template('yourPage.html')
# Respond to a request with your template.
self.response.out.write(template.render())
```

It does more than serve just static pages, so you should [*research* more here.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)